# Angular2 display subscription after console.log

Tags: angularjs, angular, observable

I have different problem.

I retrieve data from Services into variable, but this data doesn't display on screen after loading (I use Subscription for this operation). All data appears on screen when I click button with function `getMessages(){ console.log(this.messages);}`

Can you explain why?

```
import {Component, NgZone, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {GmailApiService} from "../google/api/gmailApi.service";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs/Rx";


@Component({
    selector: 'gmail-app',
    templateUrl: '/app/gmail/gmail.component.html'
})

export class GmailComponent  implements OnInit{
    public messages: Array<string>;
    subscription:Subscription;

    constructor(private gmailApi: GmailApiService){
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.gmailApi.checkAuthAuto('from:(xyz@zyx.com) OR to:(azx@saa.com)');

        this.subscription = this.gmailApi.openMessages$
            .subscribe(messages => this.messages = messages);
    }

    getMessages(){
        console.log(this.messages);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Component files:

```
<template [ngIf]="messages">
    Messages:
    <h1 *ngFor="let message of messages">**{{message?.id}}**</h1>
</template>

<button id="button-get" (click)="getMessages(event)">
    getMessages
</button>
```

---

### ---UPDATE---SOLUTIONS---

I found solutions for my problem, i add zone in subscription and now it's work correctly. Below I present part of my code after h

```
constructor(private zone:NgZone, private gmailApi: GmailApiService){
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.gmailApi.checkAuthAuto('from:(xyz@zyx.com) OR to:(azx@saa.com)');

    this.subscription = this.gmailApi.openMessages$
        .subscribe(messages => {
            this.zone.run(() => {
                this.messages = messages;
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: I cannot explain, I use the same pattern in many places and it works. Can you replicate in a plunker https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be associated with lifecycle hooks. See this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

I'm not sure but maybe you should implements doCheck and in subscribe call ngDoCheck method? Something like this:

```
export class GmailComponent  implements OnInit, DoCheck {
    public messages: Array<string>;
    subscription:Subscription;

    constructor(private gmailApi: GmailApiService){
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.gmailApi.checkAuthAuto('from:(xyz@zyx.com) OR to: (azx@saa.com)');

        this.subscription = this.gmailApi.openMessages$
                .subscribe(messages => { 
                     this.messages = messages;
                     ngDoCheck();
                  });
    }

    getMessages(){
        console.log(this.messages);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
         this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    ngDoCheck() {
        //do nothing, just call
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I add console.log into ngDoCheck() but it doesn't help. I think that everything in this subscription is called before I really have data in my Services.
I get about 10 consol.log test in ngDoCheck() but all of them before console.log form Services (with my data).

Comment: Read whole article. Probably I wrote wrong hook, sorry for mistake

Comment: I found solutions for this problem - it was partly connected with your suggestion. After subscription Angular2 doesn't trigger any of ngDoCheck() method. When I try add it manually (like in your example) it doesn't work. I look for another solutions to trigger this refresh metod and I found it - when I add zone.run() in subscription ng2 start trigger refresh check method from your article and it work correctly now.
Thanks for your help! I put solutions in my question.